# How do I refer at run-time to static resources in WPF?

Tags: wpf, treeview, binding

I have created 2 image resources and I want to dynamically refer to them from inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate of a TreeView control.

This is my XAML code:

```
  <TreeView Margin="17,22" Name="TreeView">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon1" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/icon1.ico"/>
                    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon2" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/icon2.ico"/>
                </TreeView.Resources>
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource Icon1}" Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,2,0,0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="11"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

What is the proper syntax for the Source binding of the image so that I can select at run-time which static image is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already binding against some `Name` property. Extend your (view-)model with an integer property `Icon` that determines with Icon you want to be shown for this entry. Then you can use a trigger:

```
<Image Margin="0,0,5,0" Width="16" Height="16">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource Icon1}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Icon}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource Icon2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Although I am wondering if is there a way to specify the static resource name directly from a property without resorting to a trigger?

Comment: @Chris: I don't think that's possible: Bindings can only be made on DependencyProperties, and StaticResourceExtension.ResourceKey is not a DependencyProperty. However, you could bind directly to the BitmapImage, if you want: `<Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" />`. Then, `MyImage` in your data model must contain the `BitmapImage` to show.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a better idea. My main purpose was to minimize the number of BitmapImages created.

Comment: @Chris: That should work, since data.MyImage of your data items can all point to the *same* two BitmapImages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the code-behind? In code-behind you can say

```
BitmapImage b = (BitmapImage)TreeView.FindResource("Icon1");
```

and then assign it to whichever property you need.